# How to set the rpmbuild destination folder

Tags: redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

I noticed rpmbuild (-bb and --buildroot options) creates the .rpm in different locations depending of what OS are you using:

- GNU/Linux Ubuntu <= 9.04: /usr/src/rpm/...
- GNU/Linux Ubuntu >= 9.10: /home/rpmbuild/...
- GNU/Linux Fedora: /usr/src/redhat/...

So how can I set manually the destination folder for all OS?

Comment: also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285792/how-do-you-make-topdir-relative-to-the-location-of-the-spec-file-when-building/8243413#8243413

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Replying myself, adding:

```
%define _rpmdir /outputdir
```

to .spec file.

Answer (score 13):

You may want to use the command argument `--define` : For example, this will send the rpm files into the current directory.

```
rpmbuild anything.spec --bb --define "_rpmdir $(pwd)"
```

This will send the rpmsto output dir

```
rpmbuild anything.spec --bb --define "_rpmdir /outputdir"
```

Or perhaps something more complicated such as [Custom gradle task for rpmbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525833/custom-gradle-task-for-rpmbuild) .

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to set **_topdir** to a subdirectory called **rpmbuild** inside my project. I also set a few macros, to control the **.rpm** path:

```
rpm:
rpmbuild -bb package.spec -D "_topdir $(shell pwd)/rpmbuild"  -D "SRC $(shell pwd)" -D "NAME $(NAME)" -D "ARCH $(ARCH)" -D "VERSION $(VERSION)" -D "RELEASE $(RELEASE)"
mv rpmbuild/RPMS/$(ARCH)/$(NAME)-$(VERSION)-$(RELEASE).$(ARCH).rpm ./
rm -rf rpmbuild
```

Then I use **make** to generate the **.rpm** file and move it. I prefer **rpmbuild** to operate inside its directory.

```
make rpm
```

package.spec is using these macros, e.g.

```
Name:           %{NAME_PACKAGE}
```

Comment: I use the option `--build-in-place`, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just a tiny comment..
adding "%define _rpmdir /outputdir" to spec file is also support by rpmbuild in AIX OS

Answer (score 1):

---

Setting up the rpmbuild environment in /home/ http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13

Actually it is not recommended to use /usr/src/**. I.e. by using /home/[name]/rpms/ you can work as unprivileged user. No su or sudo is required to build packages.

---