# How to set the build area for rpmbuild per-invocation

Tags: build-process, packaging, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm modifying an automated build, and want to tell `rpmbuild` to **use a specific build area when invoking it**.

This is similar to an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777737/how-to-set-the-rpmbuild-destination-folder), but more specific.

- I don't want to run any of the build commands as the root user; the aim is only to have an RPM, not to install anything into the system.
- I don't want to [require the user to change their dotfiles](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-anywhere-different-build-area.html) (e.g. `$HOME/.rpmrc`); the build should be self-contained and not affect the user's existing settings.
- I don't want to hard-code the location into the `foo.spec` file; that file should be useable as-is if the user wants to build in a different location.
- The [`--buildroot` option](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/ch-rpm-b-command.html#S2-RPM-B-COMMAND-BUILDROOT-OPTION) is not what I need; that sets a pseudo-root filesystem for the `make` part of the build process, but I need to specify the “build area” for the *entire* RPM build process.

What I'm looking for is **a hypothetical `--build-area FOODIR` option** that can be given to the `rpmbuild` command, or an equivalent environment variable. It should thus affect just that single invocation of the command and cause it to use a specified user-writable location for its build area.

I've seen references to a `_topdir` macro that seems to be what I'm talking about, but it doesn't appear to be configurable per invocation.

It would be ideal if `rpmbuild` could set up its own environment in that location when it needs it, but I don't mind setting up the directories for that per build, since that can be automated as part of the build. The goal is to **have that user-writable location exist only for the duration of the build run**, and then clean up by deleting that entire location once the RPM file is generated.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It's not documented, but **the `_topdir` macro** determines the build area.

So you can set this per-invocation with `rpmbuild --define "_topdir ${PWD}/foobar" ...` to set the directory to whatever you want.

`--define` is the key to setting values for any macro, not just _topdir.

Comment: For the particular case of Linux kernel packaging, you can pass that option through `RPMOPTS='define "foo bar"'` on the make command line.

Comment: RPM is useless if it can't even do such a simple thing like self-contained build environments without having to resort to undocumented functionality.

Comment: @FUZxxl, it is documented, but a lot of people don't know were all the documentation is.  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:RPMMacros?rd=Packaging/RPMMacros clearly mentions _topdir, and gives it's default value, and makes not of how to set it with the "--define" all in one block (near the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 4):

The --buildroot option is not what you are looking for. The name is a bit misleading as it is not changing the buildroot but instead is setting the root for the install phase of the build. RPM is basically doing a "make install" as part of the build and is then packing the results of this. The buildroot option allows you to do this install into for example /tmp/myinstallroot.

I recently had to integrate rpm package building into an automated build and had the same problem. What i did was to generate a custom .rpmmacros file with %topdir set appropriately. I then just temporarily changes HOME to the location of that custom .rpmmacros file.

```
"HOME=mytopdir rpmbuild ...".
```

Comment: Thanks, but requiring the user to change their dotfiles is not what I need. I'm trying to make the build process stand alone, so that a single command is sufficient to generate the RPM without having to make any other changes to one's user environment.

Comment: The trick is that i am not changing the the users environment. I generate an .rpmmacros file somewhere inside my build tree and then call rpmbuild with a modified $HOME.

So yes, by temporarily changing $HOME i am modifying the users environment. Unfortunately i did found another way to do it.

Comment: Ah okay, you're saying that you use a `.rpmmacros` file which is not in the actual home directory. That's an interesting approach; it seems like an awful hack though. I hope there's a cleaner way.