# How to control the rpmbuild buildroot and install directory

Tags: macros, installation, rpmbuild, buildroot

I am confused about some directories in rpmbuild.

1: buildroot: which should be used to store the files that are supposed to be installed when the binary package is installed by an end-user.

Questions:  how to control this directory? What does BuildRoot mean?

```
 $ cat 3.spec
 ..
 BuildRoot: /opt/abc
 ..
 %prep
 echo %{buildroot}
 echo  $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```

whatever I set the BuildRoot to,  I get the result which was defined in `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`. If I define `%buildroot` in `~/.rpmmacros`, I will get the result from it.

2: How do I control the destination when we install the rpm package? For example: `rpm -ivh xxx.rpm`, where the files will be installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create the subdirectories yourself in `%install` or wherever.

Example: You want to install all your files in `/opt/mypkg/` but also want a config file `/etc/mypkg.conf`. So in the `%install` section you:

```
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt/mypkg
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc
```

So you are re-creating the tree that you want installed, all with `%{buildroot}` as the equivalent of the target's `/`.

Comment: it works and thank you very much!! the install directory should be same as the directory we installed during %install section except that rpm will replace the %{buildroot} with /,  no matter what %{buildroot} is.  

how about my first question?  how to control the value of %{buildroot} in my.spec file?   seems the value or BuildRoot is useless?

Comment: `rpmbuild --buildroot='/path/to/your/buildroot/'` should work. Sorry, missed that there were two questions.

Comment: If you want to control more than just `BuildRoot`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971391/how-to-set-the-build-area-for-rpmbuild-per-invocation).

Comment: Everything is clear now.  appreciated for your help.  Thanks!