# Build RPM package to install files in target system

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm totally new to rpm package and confused about functionalities of different sections in rpm spec.

What I want to do using rpm package is just to install `examples.py` into `/usr/lib/folder` on target system(where I run rpm). The spec template I want to use is showed below. I have two questions here  :

1.If I already have `examples.py` with same file hierarchy in BuildRoot directory before I build the rpm package, do I still need the INSTALL section?

2.I want to create an empty directory if it doesn't exist in target system using rpm package. Is it enough to use `%dir directory` in `%files` section? Do I need to do something in `%install` section or included a directory in BuildRoot directory?

I guess I don't quite understand what `%files` and `%install` do, so I have those questions.

```
Name: test
Version: 1.0.0
Release: 1
Copyright: Copyright info
Group: Applications/System
BuildRoot: %{_some_directory}

%description
Brief description of software package.

%install

%files
/usr/lib/folder/example.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38408706/3489429
2. Yes. `%dir directory` in `%files` section is needed. But you also have to do:

   %install
   mkdir -p %{buildroot}directory